# Using a common dialog box, but calling different functions from diffrent activities in android

Tags: java, android

In my app i have to use same dialog box on all the activities but then on to the click of button on dialog box i need to perform different operations for different activities, i have kept a common code for dialog but then how to call different functions, here is my code:

```
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(mContext,R.style.Theme_Levels);
dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_alert);


TextView title = (TextView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.title);
title.setText("Network Error");

TextView msg = (TextView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.msg_txt);
msg.setText("The system is down, please check after some time ");

ImageView cancel = (ImageView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.cancel);
cancel.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
dialog.dismiss();
}

});

TextView continue_btn = (TextView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.continue_btn);
continue_btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.feedback_button_purple);
continue_btn.setText("Retry");
continue_btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
//TODO perform different operation depending upon from where this function has been called
dialog.dismiss();
}

});


dialog.show();
```

Comment: you can define common display layout for dialog box. But instead of defining common button click listener for all activity define it separately. Mean when you wanted to display dialog; in that activity define click listener for button separately.

Comment: I have done exactly this but with DialogFragment. In each activity I have a method that handles the dialog OK button. When I instantiate the dialog fragment I pass it the activity type. My DialogFragment then uses this activity type flag in a switch where it does this for each activity type: ((CallingActivity)getActivity()).okButtonHandler

Answer (score 0):

Create an interface, say DialogActivity, with one method "handlePositiveButton". Let all your Activities implement this interface. From the Dialog.onClick you do this:

```
DialogActivity activity = (DialogActivity) getActivity();
activity.handlePositiveButton();
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the code you have specified in a function of a Utils file.

Then pass the positive button onclick listener in that function.

Refer the below code.

```
public static void showAlertDialog(OnClickListener listener) {
    // enter your code here
   continue_btn.setOnClickListener(listener);
   // more code here
}
```